Probability of $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)=\operatorname{Bin}(n,q)$ is decreasing when $n$ increases
$\newcommand{\Bin}{\operatorname{Bin}}$I would like to show that $\mathbb P(\operatorname{Binomial}(n,p) = \operatorname{Binomial}(n,q))$ decreases when $n$ increases for a fixed pair $(p,q)$. This can be reformulated as $\mathbb P(X_n=0)$ decreases where $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n S_i$ is a lazy random walk where $S_i=-1,0,1$ with probability $p(1-q),pq+(1-p)(1-q),(1-p)q$. For $p=q$ this can be done by characteristic functions. Any ideas for general $(p,q)$? I feel like this should be well known.
P.S. This question is crossposted from mathstackexchange, where it receives no answer even after I put a bounty.
Edit: To be clear the actual question is to show for any pair of $(p,q)$, we have $P(\Bin(n,p)=\Bin(n,q))\le P(\Bin(n-1,p)=\Bin(n-1,q))$ for any $n$, and everything is independent of each other.

I don't understand your claim : if $p=q$, this can be done by characterisctic functions. Can you provide details ?

@M.Dus It is essentially this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/734339/546503

We can use the lazy random walk interpretation to show the desired result.
First, observe that it suffices to analyze a non-lazy random walk with $\pm 1$ steps. This is because taking $n$ steps in a lazy walk is like taking $\operatorname{Binomial}(n, v)$ steps in a non-lazy walk, where $v$ is the probability the lazy walk moves in a given step.
To that end, let

$\{Y_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a random walk with i.i.d. $\{-1, +1\}$ increments, where $+1$ has probability $u \in (0, 1)$,
$\{T_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a random walk with i.i.d. $\{0, +1\}$ increments, where $+1$ has probability $v \in (0, 1)$,
$X_n = Y_{T_n}$, and
$f(t) = \mathbf{P}[Y_t = 0]$.

Also suppose $\{Y_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{T_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are independent. This means $X_n$ is a random walk with i.i.d. $\{-1, 0, +1\}$ increments, stepping $-1$ with probability $(1 - u) v$ and stepping $+1$ with probability $u v$.
Relationship to the original question. $X_n$ is the lazy random walk from the question, representing the difference between the two independent binomials. $Y_t$ is the lazy walk's value after $t$ nonzero steps, and $T_n$ is the number of nonzero steps the lazy walk has taken. To specify the process in terms of $p$ and $q$ from the original question, set $u = \frac{(1 - p) q}{p (1 - q) + (1 - p) q}$ and $v = p (1 - q) + (1 - p) q$.
We wish to show $\mathbf{P}[X_n = 0]$ is strictly decreasing in $n$. The key observation is that $T_n$ is strictly stochastically increasing in $n$ (see (2) below), and we can express $\mathbf{P}[X_n = 0]$ as a function of $T_n$:
$$\begin{aligned}
    \mathbf{P}[X_n = 0]
    &= \mathbf{P}[Y_{T_n} = 0] \\
    &= \mathbf{E}\bigl[\mathbf{P}[Y_{T_n} = 0 \mid T_n]\bigr] \\
    &= \mathbf{E}[f(T_n)],
\end{aligned}$$
where the last step follows from independence of $\{Y_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{T_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.
We first show that $f(t) = \mathbf{P}[Y_t = 0]$ is strictly decreasing in $t$. This follows form a short computation:
$$\begin{aligned}
    \frac{f(t + 1)}{f(t)}
    &= \frac{\mathbf{P}[Y_{t + 1} = 0]}{\mathbf{P}[Y_t = 0]} \\
    &= \frac{\frac{(2 (t + 1))!}{((t + 1)!)^2} (u (1 - u))^{t + 1}}{\frac{(2 t)!}{(t!)^2} (u (1 - u))^t} \\
    &= u (1 - u) \cdot \frac{(2t + 2) (2t + 1)}{(t + 1)^2} \\
    &= 4 u (1 - u) \cdot \frac{(t + 1) \bigl(t + \frac{1}{2}\bigr)}{(t + 1)^2} \\
    &< 4 u (1 - u) \leq 1. && (1)
\end{aligned}$$
Having shown $f(t)$ is strictly decreasing in $t$, we now show $\mathbf{E}[f(T_n)]$ is strictly decreasing in $n$. It is clear that for all $t \in \{0, \dots, n\}$,
$$
    \mathbf{P}[T_{n + 1} > t]
    > \mathbf{P}[T_n > t]. \qquad (2)
$$
This is because $T_{n + 1}$ gets one more $\{0, +1\}$-valued step than $T_n$.
By summation by parts, for $\mathbb{N}$-valued random variables $T$,
$$
    \mathbf{E}[f(T)]
    = f(0) + \sum_{t = 0}^\infty (f(t + 1) - f(t)) \mathbf{P}[T > t]. \qquad (3)
$$
By (1), the differences $f(t + 1) - f(t)$ are all positive. Combining this with (2) and (3) implies $\mathbf{E}[f(T_{n + 1})] > \mathbf{E}[f(T_n)]$, as desired.
Remark 1. We have actually shown that if $u \neq \frac{1}{2}$ (i.e. if $p \neq q$), then $\mathbf{P}[Y_t = 0]$ decreases exponentially in $t$. I strongly suspect that $\mathbf{P}[X_n = 0]$ decreases exponentially in $n$, too, though you might need to use a concentration inequality on $T_n$ to show this.
Remark 2. Equation (3) holds for any function $f$ and $\mathbb{N}$-valued random variable under any one of the following sufficient (but not necessary) conditions:

$T$ has bounded support (so one can use linearity of expectation).
$f$ is absolutely bounded (so one can use Fubini's theorem).
$f$ is nonnegative (so one can use Tonelli's theorem).

In this application, all three conditions hold, which is why I did not dwell on them.

On strict vs. weak stochastic ordering. An earlier version of this proof claimed the following:

By a standard property of stochastic ordering, if $f(t)$ is strictly decreasing in $t$, then $\mathbf{E}[f(T_n)]$ is strictly decreasing in $n$, as desired.

The "standard" property I was thinking of is for weak (i.e. standard) stochastic ordering, not strict. I believe a strict version should hold, and it's easy enough to show for integer-valued random variables. But the details for the general version seem complicated enough that above, I replaced the appeal to the property with a direct argument. I've asked about the strict version here.

"$T_n$ is stochastically increasing in $n$, so it suffices to show that $\mathbf{P}[Y_t = 0]$ is decreasing in $t$." This is unclear to me. Cf. Simpson's paradox.

I'm a bit confused. Is $Y_t$ supposed to represent the discrepancy between the two binomial random variables in a coupling argument? Wouldn't it then take values in ${-1,0,1}$? This doesn't seem to effect the final argument too much, but would make the last computation slightly more complicated.

I've edited the answer to (1) explain the stochastic ordering aspect in more detail and (2) more explicitly connect the processes and parameters used to the original question.

"By a standard property of stochastic ordering" ... What is that property, and what is its proof?

Okay, my mistake—turns out it wasn't "standard" :). See this new question. But it was easy enough to prove for this setting that I've changed the answer to use a direct argument instead of appealing to strict stochastic ordering.

Here is a proof which also shows the exponential decay in $n$ for $p\neq q$
Let $0<p,q<1$ and $B_{n,p},B_{n,q}$ independent $\mathrm{Binomial}(n,p)$ resp. $\mathrm{Binomial}(n,q)$ distributed random variables.
Using the representation ${n \choose k}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ikt}(1+e^{it})^n\,dt$ we find
\begin{align*}
d_n:&=\mathbb{P}(B_{n,p}=B_{n,q})\\&=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^2 (pq)^k \big((1-p)(1-q)\big)^{n-k}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (pq)^k \big((1-p)(1-q)\big)^{n-k}e^{-ikt}(1+e^{it})^n\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \Big((1-p)(1-q)+pqe^{-it}\Big)^n (1+e^{it})^n\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \Big((1-p)(1-q)+pq +pqe^{-it}+ (1-p)(1-q)e^{it}\Big)^n\,dt
\end{align*}
that is, $d_n$ is the residue  of $f_n(z):= \frac{1}{z}\Big((1-p)(1-q)+pq +\frac{pq}{z}+ (1-p)(1-q)z\Big)^n$ in  0, evaluated by a circle integral
over $|z|=1$. Since $f_n(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ we may instead use the circle with $|z|=\sqrt{\frac{pq}{(1-p)(1-q)}}$ (this choice makes the integrand real) in the residue computation
and get
\begin{align*}
d_n&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \Big((1-p)(1-q)+pq +\sqrt{pq(1-p)(1-q)}(e^{-it}+ e^{it})\Big)^n\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \Big((1-p)(1-q)+pq +2\sqrt{pq(1-p)(1-q)}\,\cos(t)\Big)^n\,dt
\end{align*}
Let \begin{align*}
g:&[-\pi,\pi]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\ &t\mapsto (1-p)(1-q)+pq +2\sqrt{pq(1-p)(1-q)}\,\cos(t)
\end{align*}
Clearly $g$ is  continuous, has minima at $t=-\pi$ and $t=\pi$ given by
\begin{align*}
m(p,q):=\big(\sqrt{pq} -\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\big)^2 
\end{align*}
and has a unique maximum at $t=0$,  given by
\begin{align*}
M(p,q):=\big(\sqrt{pq} +\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\big)^2 
\end{align*}
and $m(p,q)<g(t)<M(p,q)$ for  $t\not\in \{-\pi,0,\pi\}$.
Further $\sqrt{pq}+\sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\leq 1$, with equality if and only if $p=q$.
( Since by the AGM-inequality  $\sqrt{pq}\leq\frac{1}{2}(p+q), \sqrt{(1-p)(1-q)}\leq \frac{1}{2}(2-p-q)$ with equality if and only if $p=q$).
Thus $M(p,q)\leq 1$ and $0<g^{n+1}< g^n$ a.e., therefore the  sequence $(d_n)$ is strictly decreasing. Finally, since $d_n<M(p,q)^n$ and $M(p,q)<1$ for $p\neq q$ the decrease is exponential in $n$ in these cases.
ADDED:  a much shorter derivation of the residue representation above is possible the (as noted by Dan Romik).
Consider the lazy random walk $X_n$ which stays put (step 0) with probability $pq+(1-p)(1-q)$ and steps $+1$ resp.  $-1$ with probabilities $p(1-q)$ resp. $q(1-p)$. Then
\begin{align*}
d_n=\mathbb{P}(X_n=0) &=[z^0]\,\Big(pq+(1-p)(1-q)+p(1-q)z+\frac{q(1-p)}{z}\Big)^n\\
 &=[z^{-1}]\,\frac{1}{z}\Big(pq+(1-p)(1-q)+p(1-q)z+\frac{q(1-p)}{z}\Big)^n
\end{align*}
and now computing the residue using the circle $|z|=\sqrt{\frac{(1-p)q}{(1-q)p}}$ gives
\begin{align*}
d_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \Big(pq+(1-p)(1-q) +2\sqrt{pq(1-p)(1-q)}\,\cos(t)\Big)^n\,dt
\end{align*}

Very nice argument - this feels to me like the canonical solution. By the way, your representation of $d_n$ as a residue is quite easily apparent from OP's formulation of this quantity as $P(X_n=0)$ where $X_n$ is the lazy random walk mentioned in the question. (In other words, one does not need to go through the calculation involving your integral representation of $\binom{n}{k}$, amusing though that calculation is.)

Thank you.  To me it also looks canonical - one could e.g. go easily go on above and show the local limit theorem asymptotics. I saw the simpler derivation (your suggestion) only in retrospect, but have added an explanation now.

Since you are only interested in the non-symmetric case, here is an answer. The local limit theorem states that $\mathbb P(X_n=0)\sim C\rho^{n}n^{-1/2}$, where $\rho$ is the spectral radius. Therefore, $\mathbb P(X_n=0)/\mathbb P(X_{n-1}=0)\sim \rho$. Now, since the random walk is non-centered, $\rho<1$, thus for large enough $n$, $\mathbb P(X_n=0)/\mathbb P(X_{n-1}=0)<1$, i.e. $\mathbb P(X_n=0)$ is eventually decreasing.
I do not know if the word "eventually" is necessary though.

Here's a proof, though I can't help but feel it's far too complicated (which also makes me worried I've made a mistake). On its merits, I suspect the connection to Legendre polynomials could be cleaned up. More significantly, it feels like overkill, that the whole approach is too much.
Let $B_{n,p}$ be a random variable with binomial distribution and parameter $p$, so
$$
\mathbb{P}[B_{n,p} = k] = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
$$
Then for $B_{n,p}$ and $B_{n,q}$ independent we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[B_{n,p} = B_{n,q}] & = \sum_{k = 0}^n \mathbb{P}[B_{n,p} = B_{n,q} = k]\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{P}[B_{n,p}=k] \cdot \mathbb{P}[B_{n,q}=k]\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 (pq)^k[(1-p)(1-q)]^{n-k}\\
&= [(1-p)(1-q)]^n\  _2F_1\left(-n,-n,1,\frac{pq}{(1-p)(1-q)}\right)
\end{align*}
Here, the second equality is independence and the last is from Wolfram Alpha.
From Equation (1) in Section 2.7 here, we have
$$
_2F_1(a,b,c,z) = (1-z)^{-a} \ _2F_1\left(a,c-b,c,\frac{z}{z-1}\right).
$$
With $a = b = -n$, $c = 1$ and $z = \frac{pq}{(1-p)(1-q)}$ (though we'll stick to $z$ for now), this becomes
$$
_2F_1\left (-n,-n,1,z \right) = (1-z)^n\  _2F_1\left(-n,n+1,1,\frac{z}{z-1}\right),
$$
which by Section 2.2 (11) is the Legendre polynomial $P_n\left(1-2\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$.
Evaluating $\frac{z}{z-1}$ at $z=\frac{pq}{(1-p)(1-q)}$ gives $\frac{-pq}{1-p-q}$, so we see
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[B_{n,p} = B_{n,q}] &= [(1-p)(1-q)]^n \left(1- \frac{pq}{(1-p)(1-q)}\right)^n P_n\left(1+2\cdot \frac{pq}{1-p-q}\right)\\
&= (1-p-q)^n P_n\left(\frac{pq + (1-p)(1-q)}{1-p-q}\right).
\end{align*}
Legendre polynomials satisfy the recurrence
$$
(n+1)P_{n+1}(x) = (2n+1) x P_n(x)-nP_{n-1}(x).
$$
Let $E_n = \mathbb{P}[B_{n,p} = B_{n,q}]$.
Setting $x = \frac{2pq -p-q+1}{1-p-q}$ and multiplying the previous equation through by $(1-p-q)^{n+1}$, we get
$$
(n+1)(1-p-q)^2 E_{n+1} = [\left(pq+(1-p)(1-q)\right)(2n+1) E_n - n E_{n-1}]
$$
Note $|1-p-q| < 1$.
Then the result will follow if the right-hand side is less than $(n+1) E_n$, or equivalently if
$$
[\left(pq+(1-p)(1-q)\right)(2n+1) E_n -(n+1)E_n <  n E_{n-1}.
$$
Since $pq + (1-p)(1-q) < 1$ when $p,q$ are non-degenerate, the lefthand side less than $nE_n$, which is less than $n E_{n-1}$ by the inductive hypothesis.
Edit: I made several mistakes in the final inequality, partly due to misusing the three term recurrence. It seems likely the approach can be salvaged though.

I think using the identity for the hypergeometric function is a good idea. However: you seem to have shown that $(n+1)(1-p-q)^2 E_{n+1} <(n+1) E_n$; but how do you get $E_{n+1}<E_n$ from that?

Also, your recurrence for the $E_n$'s seems incorrect. Indeed, if e.g. $q=1-p$, then your recurrence is $0=2p(1-p)(2n+1)E_n-nE_{n-1}$, so that $E_n>E_{n-1}$ if $p$ is small enough.

I think the recurrence is reversed. I get $(n+1)E_{n+1}-pq+(1-p)(1-q)E_n + (p+q-1)^2nE_{n-1}=0$, which I checked numerically.

First of all, you need to somehow specify a joint distribution; if you compute $\textrm{Bin}(X, 1/2)$ and $\textrm{Bin}(X, 1/2)$ by flipping a single fair coin $n$ times and using the outcomes to determine both random variables, then they are equal with probability $1$! It seems you're assuming independence from your reformulation.
Also, even with independence, if $p = q = 0$ or $p = q = 1$, then they are equal with probability $1$ for all $n$. So I assume you want $0 < p, q < 1$.
Regardless of joint distribution, by de Moivre-Laplace/your favorite law of large numbers/any ergodic theorem, for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$, $P(\textrm{Bin}(n,p))/n \in (p - \epsilon, p + \epsilon)) \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So if you choose $\epsilon < |p-q|/2$ I think you get your desired result for $p \neq q$.
But in the independent case there's a much simpler proof. If you take any independent random variables $X, Y$ whatsoever with values in $\mathbb{N}$, and denote $M = \max_n P(Y = n)$, then $P(X = Y) = \sum_n P(X = n) P(Y = n) \leq M \sum_n P(X = n) = M$. So it suffices to just show that the max probability of any outcome for $\textrm{Bin}(n, p)$ approaches $0$, which is fairly simple to show directly.

I think you misunderstood my question. I would like to show P(Bin(n,p)=Bin(n,q))<=P(Bin(n-1,p)=Bin(n-1,q)) for any n, and of course everything is independent, sorry for not mentioning that.

Ah sorry, I read this late at night and read "decreases" as "approaches 0," of course you're right!
